# Автоматический, физический ресаз изображений сайта под разные разрешения

Tags: php, nginx, изображения

Есть такой классный модуль для NGINX, modpagespeed. Задачи, которые на него возлагались - это автоматический ресазинг изображений, кеширование оных и показ пользователям уже кешированных картинок. Но работает это чудо очень, очень плохо, а именно, это выражается в том, что оно режет, оно кеширует, но оно новым юзерам не подставляет этот кеш. И только при повторном просмотре оно там что то внедряет эти все кеши, и то частично. Короче, такой рандом неприемлем для проекта, нужен контроль.
Есть ли готовые решения типа modpagespeed? Или все писать самому :) как всегда, эра же фреймворков и сладкого кода.

Comment: Mod Pagespeed - решение рабочее, применяется на многих серьёзных проектах. Есть и хостеры, которые включают его автоматом. Кеши он создаёт не сразу, а после нескольких обновлений страницы. Это нормально.

Comment: ну я обновил раз 50 страниц под приватным окном, потом делаю новое окно приватное, захожу а там все без кеша